# Unknown behaviour of Object Animator

Tags: android

I am trying to animate a view using ObjectAnimator defined in xml file. What I see is the animation rotates first half of the view(left part if you see the screen), but there is no animation in second half of the view. I am using Samsung phone(Lollipop version 5.0.1) to test the same.
My xml is:

```
<objectAnimator
        android:valueFrom="0"
        android:valueTo="-90"
        android:propertyName="rotationY"
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
        android:duration="@integer/card_flip_time_half" />
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want a complete rotation? In that case use valueTo="360".
Or do you want it to rotate back, then use REVERSE. 
There are a lot of things to do with property animations. Check the docs-
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#REVERSE

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Interpolator.html